# how to create multiple shortcodes in Wordpress and selectively position them anywhere in a custom template page file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my functions file I have this:

```
    function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
       return '<span class="caption">' . $content . '</span>';
    }


    add_shortcode( 'caption', 'caption_shortcode' );
```

In the CMS page editor I have this:

```
    [caption]My Caption[/caption]
```

This page is utilizing a custom template file template-mypage.php.  My question is: I would like to create multiple short codes types within the CMS such as:

```
    [caption1]My Caption[/caption1]
    [caption2]My Caption[/caption2]
    [caption3]My Caption[/caption3]
```

then in my template-mypage.php... I would like to selectively choose where to place [caption1], [caption2], [caption3]... for example [caption1] will go somewhere on the top... [caption2] in the middle and [caption3] towards the bottom of the template-mypage.php, all seperated by some huge chunks of HTML content.  I do not want to write any HTML within the WP CMS... all HTML should be written in the template-mypage.php.

Currently I believe WP limits shortcode output to come out of the_content();  Is it possible to do something like the_content_of_caption1(), the_content_of_caption2(), the_content_of_caption3()?

Thanks please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this product does this perfectly

http://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/